# How to show custom images on google maps using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can I show [these kind of car images in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3KJ5.png) on google maps
according to latitude & longitude?

I tried the following code, [but I got the following incorrect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FbZy.jpg)

```
 let marker1 = GMSMarker()
        let marker2 = GMSMarker()
        let marker3 = GMSMarker()
        let marker4 = GMSMarker()
        let marker5 = GMSMarker()
        let markerImage = UIImage(named: "white_car_icon copy.png")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

        let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)
        marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.9077923, longitude: 77.586962)
        marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.9077923, longitude: 77.586962)
        marker3.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.9077856, longitude: 77.58695950000001)
        marker4.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.90782858, longitude: 77.58678956)
        marker5.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.90780888511306, longitude: 77.58487723767757)
        marker1.iconView = markerView
        marker1.map = mapView
        marker2.iconView = markerView
        marker2.map = mapView
        marker3.iconView = markerView
        marker3.map = mapView
        marker4.iconView = markerView
        marker4.map = mapView
        marker5.iconView = markerView
        marker5.map = mapView
```

If anyone could help me with this, I'd be thankful to you. I have been trying it for the past 4 days, but didn't get correct output.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: @ammateja While using the `iconView` property and initialising it with `UIImageView`, you also have to define the frame else it will take the frame of your image which is present in your assets

Answer (score 2):

The right option is using the icon property

```
 marker5.icon = UIImage(named: "paradero")
```

With this you can set any image you want.

Comment: what is the problem with `iconView` property?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari there's no problem, he just wanted to load an image, if there's a icon property to show an image, why not using that?