# how to implement photosByLocation on map like Places in album folder in gallery photos framework

Tags: ios, photosframework, mapkitannotation

How do i implement photosByLocation on map like places in Albums photos gallery and can also sort our photos by the place.
I am able to fetch all images and locations and date taken by the photos.but not able to show the images on the map after fetch the image.

[image]

How can i implement like this.Please help me i am search more sites but not able to found any reference.Thanks in advance

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726012/how-to-show-custom-images-on-google-maps-using-swift

Comment: i have tried but not able to display different different location image on the map only able to show the one location image.any idea for display multiple location image on the map..please help me how to show.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Richie,  can you give me your gmail id pls. i will share our code to u.Actually  i have written one method for fetch all photo location latitude and longitude.and after that fetching the images by using lat and long. create a one custom annotation class for display the annotation image. Can you share your gmail id Richie. thanks

Comment: You will have to use Cluster Map of Google, or you can Google some Github codes for Cluster maps.